# Software tools to find square root modulo $2^t$

Tags: computational-number-theory, mathematical-software

Are there any software tools to find modular square roots of $y$ in $$x^2\equiv y\bmod p^t$$ where $p$ is a prime $\geq2$?

Are there any special techniques which can speed up at $p=2$?

Comment: Hensel's lemma will be easiest, once you've got a square root for $t = 1$ with $p > 2$ or (if I remember correctly) $t = 3$ with $p = 2$.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you. Any software tools?

Comment: Having custom software for Hensel's lemma seems like overkill.  I am sure it is built in to any system that can do modular arithmetic.  For example, Mathematica has [`PowerModList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerModList.html).

Comment: Ah that is good information.

Answer (score 6):

All square roots of $y$ are obtained by taking any particular square root of $y$ and multiplying it by a square root of 1. So, the problem is split into two:

- find one (any) square root of $y$;
- find all square roots of 1.

In PARI/GP, both problems are solved more or less easily. E.g., for the first problem one can employ p-adic numbers and compute `sqrt(y + O(p^t))`.

[This script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9lEuP0zAQgO-V-h8GVUh26642WThV4cSFQ1kJEJc8kJsmrLuxkzrukoL474zzdCqxPbTuvGc-j6MIeFFAfb5wnYEuS1NDmYMHsjyCn6jl4g8qtfHwv08UhQDklWi6Wy4ARE5UENwz0Jm5aEXCfXkk98yjMQXXwptbeMy_tfBHC2sQeuwhZu_oYNPLtuiYELX16GY8bb0Yj8ra_V0ulovotX6k2w2RfTOG5Uwz7bMvXTaD4hdeXLgRpSISi23F2kf5NAozlg8S60_M2MFLltalNqQQuSHap2MbOQbIeWpKLZRBtwi9epW2OTOrIpKbWvzOSE5D7E2wtvs2lk1OPNjAI8lDwbw4sT9-jBnYXAB92KGUITastL_2k5VmcGIgAnLCEb5F4Q4Owfcs1dkLOQjF9ZVYK0zVWkQr28YO2irSJ6GyOiM4kFBssEQYJX0WDP_MCPolh_A5Xmv8whHYMYyY_guqsaAuRQkSeA3mx6fP3_aPH2sgv4R5Qiz6KtTPzkZQi5PbqeA8LdFzT7RCFgyQSNGNofsgqjei7hKiKRuuZExdq2oG6XyHcV11YTP0hCpLyNGZCWJhwbW82plhYZZa1UGqempAb5x5VRVX0mw_WOQNa-6qpOJHkVY6S7v_SBramzc56iB0i8hLjTWQOnAqCXEnY8omI-uVlirleEFZOPBzPEwo4nWLsMYTxXV1Urjnr5npXoPXtk-NUEdiFpdiIOcPSl-bO4phK6LGomAnNq5DQzendSeVdi7uTdi34eXNjPEGrLR9sHr0ekZ-trfDdOh0Z6tubW_T4Kv0PnnoM7k2clKi7h_GXIXA&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) computes all square roots, even modulo composite numbers.